# An Issue with Normals and SubDivison

Tags: edit-mode, workflow, normals

A visible seam is observable during SubD operations on a boolean cut.

Prior to applying the Boolean I created supporting edge loops which are not approximately* in line, they are exactly* in line, ie. mesh topology looks so good it brings a tear to the eye.

Despite this, for the past 2 weeks this issue persists. Weighted normals and proximity loops help the overall shape, but only minimize this particular effect. A blend file should be attached. Picture illustrates issues.

[image]

[image: Issue]
[image: Edge Norms]
[image: Vert Norms]

Is anyone able to identify this issue, and what the solution is?

Comment: Did u try increasing mean crease near that area?

Comment: I did yes, thank you though. Most of those solutions only minimized the issue, apparently it was bad topo! Took me by surprise as everything was quaded rather nice, but the answer I've marked below shows the version which seems to work. I think the gist is to really drive home a full perimeter edge loop around any of these sort of things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your topology is not good, if we enable the *Subdivision Surface* modifier *On Cage* display option, here is what it gives, the central vertex is completely stretched, which gives the bad result:

[image]

If you choose this topology it will work fine:

[image]

Comment: So it is! I drummed up a different solution, but all of them seem to rely on having a proximity edge loop between the edge proper and the rest of the mesh to sort out the issues. I didn't realize that was, or could really, be an issue until today! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Merge by distance <kbd>M</kbd>><kbd>B</kbd> and change the threshold until you've removed enough vertices to minimize the seam.

Then add an edge loop to support the geometry in front of that area.

See the gif below for a visual:

[image]

---

Note that this will fix the issue for now, but in the future, you should consider better topology, and not strictly rely on booleans for modeling.

[topology guides](https://topologyguides.com/) is a good resource to begin with, and there are many questions here on the site that will lead in the right direction also.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the suggestion. I didn't use a boolean, but it was an easier way of describing the process. I find it odd though, I created and positioned loops to be perfectly perpendicular to the project, I'll need to look at my topo again to see what specifically was the issue there maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few solutions:

1. bevel around the area selected as shown below

[image]

2. add an edge loop and move it the direction as shown below

[image]

Comment: Hi there, thanks for this! After posting this question those were some the things I tried, and they all helped indeed! But it seems the issue was with the way I set up topo here, I thought I had it set but no dice! Cheers